# Pragma Mark in Symbol Navigator XCode 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

How do I get the `pragma` marks to show up in the Symbol Navigator in XCode?

As you see below, the pragma marks show up in the Jump Bar but doesn't appear on the left side in the Symbol Navigator.

I've tried to sort by type through the Edit menu, but it's greyed-out for anything highlighted in the Symbol Navigator.

[image: pragma not in symbol navigator]
[image: edit greyed out]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the marks are available, once Xcode finished indexing the project. The status of indexing can be seen, if you expand the title bar.

Is the project really "PragmaWTF"?

Comment: The project is indexed and the problem persists. Just had to think of some name to show the reproduced problem :P

Comment: Have you also tried it using a Swift file? May be it's a temporary problem that will be fixed by the next update, but is not present for Swift...

Comment: Swift doens't have `#pragma`.